# How do you accept multiple values for a switch case?

Tags: c++, switch-statement, case

How does one accept more than one value for a single case in C++? I know you can make a range of values for one case (e.g. `case 1..2`) in some other languages, but it doesn't seem to be working in C++ on Xcode.

```
int main() {
    int input;
    cin >> input;
    switch (input) {
        case 1:
            cout << "option 1 \n";
            break;
        case 2..3: //This is where the error occurs
            cout << "option 2 and 3 \n";
            break;
        
        default:
            break;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The program shows an error saying "Invalid suffix '.3' on floating constant" where the range is.

Comment: Advice -- do not use another computer language as a guide in writing C++ code.  If you go down that road of trying to make C++ look like your other favorite computer language, you will wind up with buggy code, inefficient programs, or code that looks plain weird to a C++ programmer.

Comment: To be honest, any decent book, tutorial or class should have taught you how to do this.

Comment: I have found that there is a lot of syntax in other languages that doesn't work in C++.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can "fall through" by having sequential `case` statements without a `break` between them.

```
switch (input) {
    case 1:
        cout << "option 1 \n";
        break;
    case 2:
    case 3:
        cout << "option 2 and 3 \n";
        break;
    
    default:
        break;
}
```

Note that *some* compilers support range syntax like `case 50 ... 100` but this is non-standard C++ and will likely not work on other compilers.

Comment: Worth noting also that large ranges are better checked in an if/else block.

Answer (score 5):

You could simply do:

```
switch (input) {
        case 1:
            cout << "option 1 \n";
            break;
        case 2: [[fallthrough]]
        case 3:
            cout << "option 2 and 3 \n";
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
```

Note that `case 2 ... 3` is called [case ranges](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Case-Ranges.html), and is a non-standard gcc extension that you could use.

Answer (score 2):

You can't do a range of values, but you can do multiple values:

```
switch (input) {
    case 1:
        cout << "option 1 \n";
        break;
    case 2: case 3: case 4:
        cout << "option 2 or 3 or 4\n";
        break;
    
    default:
        break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use spaces between them with three(...)

```
int main() {
    int input;
    cin >> input;
    switch (input) {
        case 1:
            cout << "option 1 \n";
            break;
        case 2 ... 3: //This is where the error occurs
            cout << "option 2 and 3 \n";
            break;
        
        default:
            break;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This is true, but it's not standard c++, it's a gcc extension.